# Laravel use where and multiple whereHas

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, orm

I want to apply filter to User's posts with this code :

```
        $user = $request->userid;
        $query = Post::query()
            ->where('post.owner.username', $username)
            ->when($request->filled('userid'), function (Builder $query) use ($user) {
                    $query->whereHas('tags', function (Builder $q) use ($user) {
                        $q->where('taggeduser.id', $user);
                    })->orWhereHas('comments', function (Builder $q) use ($user) {
                        $q->where('comment.owner.id', $user);
                    });
            })
            ->when($request->filled('searchText'),
                function (Builder $query) use ($username, $searchText) {
                    $query->whereRaw(['post.owner.username' => ['$eq' => $username]]);
                    $query->getQuery()->projections = ['score' => ['$meta' => 'textScore']];
                    $query->whereRaw(['$text' => ['$search' => $searchText]])->orderByDesc('post.taken_at_timestamp');
                })
            ->when($request->filled('location'),
                function (Builder $query) use ($location) {
                    $query->where('post.location.id', $location);
                });
```

everything is fine except request has userid, it goes through `->when($request->filled('userid')` and the result is empty,
I want to fetch users that has been tagged or commented in user's posts, giving userid to 'tags' and 'comments' relations, i have result in `$q->where('taggeduser.id', $user);`
[image]

but `$query->get()` is empty.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$user = $request->userid;
        $query = Post::where('post.owner.username', $username)
            ->when($request->filled('userid'), function (Builder $query) use ($user) {
                    $query->whereHas('tags', function (Builder $q) use ($user) {
                        $q->where('taggeduser.id', $user);
                    })->orWhereHas('comments', function (Builder $q) use ($user) {
                        $q->where('comment.owner.id', $user);
                    });
            })
            ->when($request->filled('searchText'),
                function (Builder $query) use ($username, $searchText) {
                    $query->whereRaw(['post.owner.username' => ['$eq' => $username]]);
                    $query->getQuery()->projections = ['score' => ['$meta' => 'textScore']];
                    $query->whereRaw(['$text' => ['$search' => $searchText]])->orderByDesc('post.taken_at_timestamp');
                })
            ->when($request->filled('location'),
                function (Builder $query) use ($location) {
                    $query->where('post.location.id', $location);
                })->get();
```

Comment: still no result , but i have 2 records in tags for 1 post and it returns nothing.